# Post request with Akka http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have this post request and have two issues.

1.is with the `headers` value. The documentation says it takes in a `Seq[HttpHeader]` and I pass in a `Seq[RawHeader]` which extends `HttpHeader` but it says it's a type mismatch. Why?

2.I pass in the data I want to post, but the `HttpEntity.Default()` takes in a `Source[Bytestring]`. How do I convert my `data` to `Source[Bytestring]`

```
def post(data: String): Unit = {
    val headers = Seq(RawHeader("X-Access-Token", "access token"))
    val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
      Http(system).singleRequest(
        HttpRequest(
        HttpMethods.POST,
        "https://beta-legacy-api.ojointernal.com/centaur/user",
        headers,
        entity = HttpEntity.Default(data)
        )
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I pass in a  Seq[RawHeader] which extends HttpHeader but it says it's
>   a type mismatch. Why?

Because `Seq[A]` is invariant in `A`.

> How do I convert my data to Source[Bytestring]

You don't have to. You can use use the `HttpEntity` apply method which takes an `Array[Byte]`, and use `withHeaders`:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._

def post(data: String): Unit = {
  val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
    Http(system).singleRequest(
      HttpRequest(
        HttpMethods.POST,
        "https://beta-legacy-api.ojointernal.com/centaur/user",
        entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, data.getBytes())
        ).withHeaders(RawHeader("X-Access-Token", "access token"))
    )
}
```